# android surfaceview is no longer visible after back from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

i have a question in developing some android program...

i use surfaceview for camera preview. it works fine, but has one problem when i start other activity (by clicking something) and then back from that activity. after that, surfaceview is no longer visible. (but onclicklistener is working)

but when i occur surfacecreated/destoryed by visible/invisible surfaceview in single activity, it works very good.

plz give me any help.

Comment: Was there an update to this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2.0 and 2.1-update1 issue. Was unable to reproduce on 2.2 and 1.5, 1.6.
Canvas of the SurfaceView just displays black after returning from another activity.
If you happen to find a workaround please note me.